# How can you load in an MPS file into CPLEX?

Tags: cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I wanted to use the "IBM CPLEX Optimizer Studio " to open an MPS file and solve it. I could find [instructions on how the MPS file should look like](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ar/icos/20.1.0?topic=standard-records-in-mps-format), but nothing on how to actually load it in.

I would be so happy if someone knew how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Easy optimization with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) you have a [read lp example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooimportmodel.mod)

```
main
{
  cplex.importModel("zoo.lp");
  cplex.solve();
  writeln("obj = ",cplex.getObjValue());
  
}

/*
which gives
obj = 3800
*/
```

You can do the same with .mst file

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the standalone command-line version of CPLEX which is lighter-weight than using the full CPLEX IDE. It is often quicker and easier than using the Optimisation Studio environment. On Windows this gets installed in a folder like:

C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\bin\x64_win64

but this will vary with different versions of CPLEX, different operating systems etc of course.

Easy to run from a standard command-prompt window as it usually gets added to the PATH, so you should be able to start it by just typing 'cplex', then read the MPS file (or any of several other formats) and solve it with 'opt', then display the solution variable values like this:

[image: Screenshot of command prompt running CPLEX]